# Oracle rank() with conditions

Tags: oracle, rank

I want to examine behaviors of customers when they buy a 2nd product after the 1st product with no delinquency (they borrow money from us to buy mobile phones).

My supervisor suggests creating a table like

```
Client_id  Contract_date  Contract_id  no_days_pd Rank
1          01-Jan-2015    123          (null)     1
1          01-May-2015    456          don't care 2
1          01-Aug-2015    789          don't care 3
```

and examine contracts having rank = 2 only. In this table, no_days_pd means number of days past due date, and `null` means that there was no delinquency during all instalments.

Can I do this using rank() function in Oracle? How can I impose some conditions on the rank, like,

```
when product = 'Mobile' and no_days_pd is null then rank = 1
```

I get stuck at how to let it proceed to rank = 2, 3... I want to `order by Contract_date` to ensure rank 2 contract is after the first contract with no delinquency.

Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

EDITED to check the days_past_due of the previous contract

```
with thetable as (
select 1 client_id,      to_date('01-Jan-2015','dd-mon-yyyy')  contract_Date,  123  contract_id ,  null days_past_due from dual union
select 1 client_id,      to_date('01-May-2015','dd-mon-yyyy')  contract_Date,  456  contract_id ,  12 days_past_due from dual union
select 1 client_id,      to_date('01-Aug-2015','dd-mon-yyyy')  contract_Date,  789  contract_id ,  99 days_past_due from dual union
-- add client 2 which shouldn't appear as first contract is past due
select 2 client_id,      to_date('01-Jan-2015','dd-mon-yyyy')  contract_Date,  444  contract_id ,  31 days_past_due from dual union
select 2 client_id,      to_date('01-May-2015','dd-mon-yyyy')  contract_Date,  555  contract_id ,  1 days_past_due from dual 
)
    SELECT * from (
        select client_id
             , contract_date
             , contract_id
             , days_past_due
             , row_number() over (partition by client_id order by contract_Date asc) contract_rank
             , lag(days_past_due) over (partition by client_id order by contract_date) prev_contract_past_due
        from thetable 
    ) 
    where contract_Rank = 2 and prev_contract_past_due is null
```

Comment: This gives everything I need! Thanks @Michael!